# Error when trying to get a bundle from another activity

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to retrieve a bundle from another activity but when I try this, the following error appears in my logs: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.os.Bundle.getInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`

The part of the code where I try to retrieve and show the bundle is this:

```
Bundle bundlefrankrijk = getIntent().getExtras();
    int scorefrankrijk = bundlefrankrijk.getInt("finalScoreFrankrijk");

    TextView highscoreLabelfranrkijk = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.highscorefrankrijk);

    SharedPreferences settingsfrankrijk = getSharedPreferences("GAME_DATA", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int highScorefrankrijk = settingsfrankrijk.getInt("HIGH_SCORE", 0);

    if (scorefrankrijk > highScorefrankrijk) {
        highscoreLabelfranrkijk.setText("High Score : " + scorefrankrijk);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settingsfrankrijk.edit();
        editor.putInt("HIGH_SCORE", scorefrankrijk);
        editor.commit();
    } else {
        highscoreLabelfranrkijk.setText("High Score : " + highScorefrankrijk);
    }
```

This is how I'm sending the intent to the current activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(QuizActivityFrankrijk.this, 
QuizResultaatFrankrijk.class);
            Bundle bundlefrankrijk = new Bundle(0);
            bundlefrankrijk.putInt("finalScoreFrankrijk", mScoreFrankrijk);
            i.putExtras(bundlefrankrijk);
            QuizActivityFrankrijk.this.finish();
            startActivity(i);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Better if you could post the code to see how you are sending the intent with extras to current activity too, for what I´m seeing here, the error is in this line:

```
Bundle bundlefrankrijk = getIntent().getExtras(); // is returning null object
```

And when youre trying to:

```
int scorefrankrijk = bundlefrankrijk.getInt("finalScoreFrankrijk"); // NullPointerException throwed
```

Cause your bundle is null from beginning, you should check if you´re sending correctly the intent with extras, please use the method:

`mIntent.putExtra("key", intValue)`

and check that youre receiving it like this:

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null){    
     getIntent().getExtras().getInt("key");}
```

or just like this too:

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null){
     getIntent().getExtras().get("key");}
```

Remember, if the `key` is just different in some character, it will return NULL.

Please read this for more info: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: I could add: use constants as keys as a typo is very easy to make. Plus it's easier to trace where the key is used.

Comment: I've added the code where you can see how I am sending the intent to the current activity, but I still don't know how to adapt your answer to my code